# How to start a chat conversation between the logon user and another user in the same AAD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, chat, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working on SPFx web part where a user will see the presence of other users and I want to let them click on the picture and start a TEAMS conversation with that other user.
I was expecting MS graph to have that option but all I can see is chat to a channel and or team.
My need is to be able to chat between users of any teams within the same 365 organization (AAD)
Any one knows a JavaScript way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please look at [ChatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: This has examples to send to a team channel. POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages I want to send it directly to a user. I tried changing to POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/messages  but got error.

Answer (score 0):

This is something we are working on. Currently there are no Graph API available to send message to a user in personal scope. We don't have ETA to share with you. You can have a Bot which can help to send messages in personal scope, Group chat or channel conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very long after the original post, but in case this is still a requirement - it sounds from your question like a simple deep link would work fine, as you can "deep link" to a chat with another user - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) for more. If the users have not chatted before, the deep link will actually start the chat for the first time, when the first message is sent.

Comment: maybe upvote/mark as answer in case anyone else stumbles on this in future